# Jquery event for option box and typing action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing the jquery event programming for option box for premium box.

For example, i can type on the option box.

So, I type in the option box  instead of selecting my select option box.

the following code is the example:

But seems like it is not correct. Is the event is 'change' event ?

My HTML code is as following:

```
<div id = 'divContent'>
    <select id="my_id" style="width: 120px;"
      onchange="$('input#my_id').val($(this).find('option:selected').text());"
      name="my_id">
    <option value="10000">10000</option>
    <option value="20000">20000</option>
    <option value="30000">30000</option>
    <option value="50000">50000</option>
    <option value="80000">80000</option>
    <option value="100000">100000</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your `HTML` code for that element, are you talking about any plugin, if so, then post the plugin link too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `my_id` with the id of your select box:

```
$("#divContent").on('change', "select[id='my_id']", function () {
```

Will work only when you have a select like:

```
<select id="my_id"> 
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any elements with the id divContent so change the first line to

```
$("select[id='my_id']").on('change', function () {
```

Secondly, even when the code is working, with the example given, there won't be any alerts because none of the if statements will evaluate to true

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here -

```
if (selectedValue = '') {
        alert("Please enter Premium")
    }
```

it should be == not =

```
if (selectedValue == '') {
        alert("Please enter Premium");
    }
```

you can also use -

`if(!selectedValue)` or `if(selectedValue == null)`